# $scope.$watch with angular-material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Want to change the route (ui.router) when someone close the form ( in a sidenav).

When I click on cancel everything work return on the root url but when I click on anywhere on the page and the sideNav closed I stay on the /new.

I'm new to Angular and Angular-Material

```
(function () {

"use strict";

angular
        .module("ngClassifieds")
        .controller('newClassifiedsCtrl', function ($mdSidenav, $state , $mdDialog, classifiedsFactory, $timeout, $scope){

            var vm = this;
            vm.closeSidebar = closeSidebar;

            $timeout(function(){
                $mdSidenav('left').open();
            });

            $scope.$watch('vm.sidenavOpen', function(sidenav){
                if(sidenav === false){
                    $mdSidenav('left')
                            .close()
                            .then(function(){
                                $state.go('classifieds');
                            });
                }
            });

            function closeSidebar() {
                vm.sidenavOpen = false;
            }
})
})();
```

and in the template

```
<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2"
        md-component-id="left"
        md-is-open="vm.sidenavOpen">
<md-toolbar>
    <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Add a Classified</h1>
</md-toolbar>
<md-content layout-padding>
    <form>
        <md-input-container>
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text"
                   id="title"
                   md-auto-focus
                   ng-model="classified.title">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
            <label for="price">Price</label>
            <input type="text"
                   id="price"
                   ng-model="classified.price">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
            <label for="description">Description</label>
        <textarea id="description"
                  ng-model="classified.description"></textarea>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
            <label for="image">Image Link</label>
            <input type="text"
                   id="image"
                   ng-model="classified.image">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-button class="md-primary"
                   ng-click="vm.saveClassified(classified)"
                   ng-if="!editing">
            Save
        </md-button>
        <md-button ng-if="editing"
                   class="md-primary"
                   ng-click="vm.saveEdit()">
            Save Edit
        </md-button>
        <md-button class="md-warn" ng-click="vm.closeSidebar()">
            Cancel
        </md-button>

        <pre>{{ classified | json }}</pre>
    </form>
</md-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are watching vm.sidenavOpen variable to detect sidevav close which is triggered only when you click on cancel button and not on click outside. Instead of using vm.sidenavOpen to detect sidenav close you could try something like this

**HTML**

```
<md-sidenav id="sideNav" class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left" md-is-open="vm.sidenavOpen"> //  add id='sideNav'
    .
    .
    .
</md-sidenav>
```

**Controller**

```
var firstTime = true;    // to ignore sidenav closed state on page load
$scope.$watch(function(){
    return (!(document.getElementById('sideNav').getAttribute('class').indexOf('md-closed-remove') != -1) && (document.getElementById('sideNav').getAttribute('class').indexOf('md-closed') != -1))
}, function(value) {
    if(value && !firstTime) {
        $state.go('/classifieds')   // happens every time sidenav goes to closed state (even on click outside)
    } else
        firstTime = false;
})
```